# How to add a ListView to a Fragment

Tags: listview, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment, android-listfragment

I am writing code for adding a ListView to a Fragment.
And the ListView data is retrieved from an another Class (by using an ArrayList).
But I can't add the ListView to my fragment.

Here is my code.
Guys, can you suggest me what to do?

```
public class StartFragment extends Fragment {


    DataSource dataSource;
    ArrayList<Employee> arrayList;
    ListView listView;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    Context context;

    public StartFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        arrayList = dataSource.getAllEmployee();
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(context,arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Following is the startFragment layout code...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.softmaker.gazi_opu.ourpresentation.StartFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is the custom layout for the ListView items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Name: "
            android:id="@+id/name_textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Designation: "
            android:id="@+id/designationtextView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Salary: "
            android:id="@+id/salarytextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in your this

```
listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

to this

```
listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Answer (score -1):

It does not work. Here I am retriving data from the database using arraylist.I am new in Fragment.Is there any option to load arrylist in a fragment.I wrote this code for fragment because when I wrote code for listview in a activity it's work properly. But In fragment it does not work.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.